# compressing a video in iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687341/iphoneprogrammatically-compressing-recorded-video-to-share) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751883/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-video-created-with-uiimagepickercontroller), neither have been able to help.

I have tried the following:

```
- (void)compress:(NSURL *)videoPath completionBlock:(void(^)(id data, BOOL result))block{
    self.outputFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.mov"];
    NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.outputFilePath];
    [self compressVideoWithURL:self.movieURL outputURL:outputURL handler:^(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession) {

    }];
}

- (void)compressVideoWithURL:(NSURL*)inputURL
                   outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL
                     handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))handler {

    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:self.movieURL];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];
    exportSession.fileLengthLimit = 3000000;
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        NSData *newOutputData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:outputURL];
        NSLog(@"Size of New Video(bytes):%d",[newOutputData length]);
    }];
}
```

I know that `self.movieUrl` is not `nil`. But when I printed the size (in bytes) of the `NSData` associated with the video, they were the same before and after, both 30,000,000 bytes.

But according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687341/iphoneprogrammatically-compressing-recorded-video-to-share), the above code should work.

What am I doing wrong exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have figured it out, thanks to this question (Swift version): [IOS Video Compression Swift iOS 8 corrupt video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521789/ios-video-compression-swift-ios-8-corrupt-video-file)

I have the objective C version. Here is the method:

```
 - (void)compressVideo:(NSURL*)inputURL
        outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL
          handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))completion  {
AVURLAsset *urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:urlAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    completion(exportSession);
  }];
}
```

And calling the method:

```
NSURL* uploadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                     [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temporaryPreview.mov"]];

[self compressVideo:self.movieURL outputURL:uploadURL handler:^(AVAssetExportSession *completion) {
    if (completion.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
        NSData *newDataForUpload = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:uploadURL];
        NSLog(@"Size of new Video after compression is (bytes):%d",[newDataForUpload length]);
    }
}];
```

This reduced the file size of my videos from 32 MB to 1.5 MB.

Comment: i also want to compress the video file, i implemented this code but it is not going in the successful completion handler.Can you please tell how you managed to achieve it

Comment: i am facing the same issue. Its not come in sucess.

Answer (score 21):

**In Swift 3.0**

**Select video from Camera roll**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
     if info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? String == (kUTTypeMovie as? String) {
        // here your video capture code
        let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: videoURL! as URL)!
        print("File size before compression: \(Double(data.length / 1048576)) mb")
        let compressedURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + NSUUID().uuidString + ".m4v")
        compressVideo(inputURL: videoURL as! URL, outputURL: compressedURL) { (exportSession) in
                guard let session = exportSession else {
                    return
                }

                switch session.status {
                case .unknown:
                    break
                case .waiting:
                    break
                case .exporting:
                    break
                case .completed:
                    guard let compressedData = NSData(contentsOf: compressedURL) else {
                        return
                    }
                   print("File size after compression: \(Double(compressedData.length / 1048576)) mb")
                case .failed:
                    break
                case .cancelled:
                    break
                }
            }
       }
       self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

**Compression type :**

```
AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
AVAssetExportPreset640x480 
AVAssetExportPreset960x540
```

**Compress video method**

```
 func compressVideo(inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL, handler:@escaping (_ exportSession: AVAssetExportSession?)-> Void) {
        let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL, options: nil)
        guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality) else {
            handler(nil)

            return
        }

        exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
            handler(exportSession)
        }
    }
```

**Output :**

```
File size before compression: 25.0 mb
File size after compression: 7.0 mb
```

Comment: I tried this code, but everytime my session status is Failed

Comment: I got it correct now, my compressedURL was wrong. I intially tried with                 let compressedURL = URL(string: NSTemporaryDirectory())?.appendingPathComponent("video.mp4")

Comment: @Sneha ok fine any thing else you need help

Comment: awesome answer :)