# The imagePicker seems to provide a compressed video file by default?! Is it customizable? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiimagepickercontroller

Part of my app is a chat. Within this chat a user could upload images and videos to a storage (firebase).

It works so far. Whereas uncompressed video files are huge (0:43min video has 24mb), i'd implemented the code described here and it compresses the video-file from 24mb to 1mb (lowest quality):

- [IOS Video Compression Swift iOS 8 corrupt video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521789/ios-video-compression-swift-ios-8-corrupt-video-file) or
- [compressing a video in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096928/compressing-a-video-in-ios?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But i was wondering that the imagePickerController shows a progress bar with text "compressing video" whether or not i've implemented the code from above?!

[image]

I found out (by sending file via Air Drop from iphone to macbook) that the "original" file has a size of 53mb. This is twice as much as i get out of

```
let videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL
let data = NSData(contentsOf: videoUrl!)
print("File size before compression: \(Double(data.length))")
```

It seems that a compression takes place. Could i customize this process of compression? or do i have to go the long way with `AVAssetExportSession` (described within the two links)?