# PHAsset video compression iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, upload, phasset

I am trying to upload images and videos to server. it working fine. the problem I am facing is the picture captured or video recorded from the iphone having too much size and it takes time to upload to server. how can i reduce the size of video data ?

```
if(asset.mediaType == .video)
{           
    var dataMOV : Data?

    manager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: option2, resultHandler:  {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) in
        let avURLAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset
        do
        {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: (avURLAsset?.url)!)
            dataMOV = data
            print("asset data :%@ ", data)
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521789/ios-video-compression-swift-ios-8-corrupt-video-file

Comment: Thanks, @KingofMasses, but how can I use it with phasset object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687341/iphoneprogrammatically-compressing-recorded-video-to-share/5853354#5853354 look into this ,  AVAssetExportSession can help.

Answer (score 1):

From AssetInfo, pull the asset URL and pass it to below method

```
func compressVideo(inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL, handler:@escaping (_ exportSession: AVAssetExportSession?)-> Void) {
        let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL, options: nil)
        guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality) else {
            handler(nil)

            return
        }

        exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
            handler(exportSession)
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this helped ?

Comment: Can its usage be shown?, I tried it the following way: var outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("compressed.mp4")
            compressVideo(inputURL: vidData, outputURL: outputURL) { (exportSession) in
                outputURL = exportSession!.outputURL!
                print(outputURL, "put url and also the old val : ", exportSession!.outputURL!)
            }

Comment: The issue I found is that it produces a video of length 0